# JQuery click method on asp.net Menu item?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, menuitem

I have asp.net Menu Item `<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="Download" Value="Download"/>`. When this item gets clicked, I want to execute jQuery click method. How can we do that?

Comment: Please post the HTML that control generates.

Comment: <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)" id="ctl00_Menu1n16">
   <td><table class="ctl00_Menu1_7" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="ctl00_Menu1_1 ctl00_Menu1_6" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Menu1','Reports\\Download')">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
   </table></td>
  </tr>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide a `CssClass` property with some class to the menu item. On client side find the element using that class and attach click event handler to it.

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" CssClass="menuItem" Text="Download" Value="Download"/>
```

Js

```
$('.menuItem').click(function(){
    //do stuff here
});
```

**Update:**

I think you can specify the css class in this way.

```
<asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server">
    ..
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" CssClass="menuItem" Text="Download" Value="Download"/>
    ..
    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem" />
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Or clientID can be used as a selector

Comment: Yes, `ClientID` can be used but you have to send the id to the client.

Comment: Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'CssClass' is not a valid attribute of element 'MenuItem'.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Still the same error. I defined StaticMenuItemStyle.

Comment: Now, you can check another answer. Please go through it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

### Sample JQuery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $(".MyMenu a").each(function (index) {
             $(this).click(function () {
                 alert(index);
                 return false;
             });
        });
   });
</script>
```

---

### Modified HTML

```
<asp:Menu ID="_mainMenu" RenderingMode="Table" runat="server" CssClass="MyMenu" autopostback="true">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Index" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

---

**Note** - `RenderingMode="Table"`

Comment: Above function executing when you root menu , not menu item. If we have 2 or 3 menu item... how to mange the click?

Comment: I have added one more MenuItem. Now you can check, on clicking the Index will show alert value 1 and on clicking the Home will show the value 0.

Comment: Rendering the menu as a table is a very bad practice.

Comment: Sorry.. @PankajGarg I have sub menu item in menu item... Thats the reason I am not getting sub menu item index. I am able to get root menu item index.