# How to stop ongoing postback (long running execution) on asp.net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

aspx web page and I am submitting some filter text to page to load the data using javascript and displaying progress till the result returned, but in some case when the execution takes long time to return the result user should be able to cancel the ongoing execution on server and progress should be removed.

I have hide the progress bar on click of html button, but how I can stop the on going execution on server so it don't return the result or the returned result don't get rendered later on.

is there a way to stop on going postback on asp.net using JavaScript ?

Comment: Are you using MVC or webforms?

Comment: Hi @Dinesh I am not using MVC, I am using web forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below...It's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335389/cancel-requests-on-link-clicked-asp-net)

```
function cancelPostBack() {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
    prm.abortPostBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to add it in update panel ? I have script manager added in page but I am not using any update panel. I am getting prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()  as false.